# How to easily print default Git author info?

Tags: git

Basically, is there a simpler equivalent of `printf '%s <%s>\n' "$(git config --get user.name)" "$(git config --get user.email)"` to get a string like "My Name <email@example.org>" built into Git?

The end goal is to simplify [the following Git alias](https://gitlab.com/engmark/root/-/merge_requests/365/diffs?commit_id=9ae12d85d5d5e6b41d8a23cc6ff015fa992705f5):

```
co-author !git commit --amend --message="$(git show --format=%B --no-patch HEAD)" --message="$(printf 'Co-Authored-By: %s <%s>' "$(git config --get user.name)" "$(git config --get user.email)")"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command can be shorter, although the `printf` part is not shortened the way you might expect.

```
git commit --amend --no-edit --trailer Co-Authored-By="$(git config user.name) <$(git config user.email)>"
```

If you want to edit the commit message, remove `--no-edit`.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider using the git config --global --get-regexp command with a pattern, although it's not much shorter:

```
git config --global --get-regexp 'user\.(name|email)'
```

This will give you an output like:

```
user.name Your Name
user.email your.email@example.com
```

Comment: That would still need to be re-formatted to achieve the same effect, so the end result would be much longer.

Comment: Well, it didn't answer the question, which was very specific. And the original question already included code to get the two relevant values. So the answer doesn't help.